# Unable to get drop-down box to auto-populate AJAX PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to set up a form where clients can enter their shipping information for items they order from my site.  I ship to the US and Canada, so I would like to have them select either "United States" or "Canada" from the country drop-down box, and then use ajax and php to create a select option list of states/provinces for the selected country without reloading the page.

My Code so far:

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/functions.php';

include_once 'header.php';

?>

<h1>Shipping Information</h1>

<p>Please use the form below to add a shipping address to your account.  You MUST have a shipping address on file to be able to access our store.  For a list of accepted state/provice and country codes, please visit <a href="https://www.ups.com/worldshiphelp/WS14/ENU/AppHelp/Codes/State_Province_Codes.htm" target="_blank">here</a>.  We only ship to the United States and Canada at this time.</p>

<div id="form">
<form action="" method="post">
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="550">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Add Shipping Address</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    if($error)
    {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">';
        echo $error;
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="fname">First Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="lname">Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="addr1">Address</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="addr1" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="addr2">Apt/Suite/Unit</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="addr2" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="city">City</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="cc">Country</label></td>
        <td>
            <select name="cc" id="cc">
                <option value="">Select One...</option>
                <option value="US">United States</option>
                <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="sp">State/Province</label></td>
        <td id="response"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="pcode">Postal Code</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pcode" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="active">Set Default</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="active" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Address" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

<script>
$("#cc").on("change",function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:POST,
        url:"process-request.php",
        data: { cc : selected },
        contentType:"application/json; charset-utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        async:false,
        success: ccSuccess,
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
});

function ccSuccess(result)
{
    $("#response").html(result);
}

function AjaxFailed(result)
{
    $("#response").html("<p class='error'>Failed to Load State/Province Codes</p>");
}
</script>

<?php

include_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

My process-request.php file:

```
<?php
// process-request.php

if(isset($_POST['cc']))
{
    $country = $_POST['cc'];
    $countryArr = array(
        "US" => array(
        'AL',
        'AK',
        'AZ',
        'AR',
        'CA',
        'CO',
        'CT',
        'DE',
        'DC',
        'FL',
        'GA',
        'HI',
        'ID',
        'IL',
        'IN',
        'IA',
        'KS',
        'KY',
        'LA',
        'ME',
        'MD',
        'MA',
        'MI',
        'MN',
        'MS',
        'MO',
        'MT',
        'NE',
        'NV',
        'NH',
        'NJ',
        'NM',
        'NY',
        'NC',
        'ND',
        'OH',
        'OK',
        'OR',
        'PA',
        'RI',
        'SC',
        'SD',
        'TN',
        'TX',
        'UT',
        'VT',
        'VA',
        'WA',
        'WV',
        'WI',
        'WY'
        ),
        "CA" => array(
        'AB',
        'BC',
        'MB',
        'NB',
        'NL',
        'NT',
        'NS',
        'NU',
        'ON',
        'PE',
        'QC',
        'SK',
        'YT'
        )
    );
    if($country !== 'Select One...')
    {
        echo "<select name='sp'>";
        foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
}
?>
```

My header.php and footer.php just contain formatting divs for the page layout, as well as links for css and the javascript href "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js".

I have no idea what is missing, or what I am doing wrong, as this is my first time dealing with javascript, and I have tried several tutorials on how to do this, all of which did not work when I change the selection.

If I change the selection for country, nothing updates at all for the state/province section, #response.

UPDATE:
I was able to get everything working with the following code snippets:

```
<div id="form">
<form action="" method="post">
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="550">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Add Shipping Address</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    if($error)
    {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">';
        echo $error;
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="fname">First Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="lname">Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="addr1">Address</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="addr1" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="addr2">Apt/Suite/Unit</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="addr2" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="city">City</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="cc">Country</label></td>
        <td>
            <select name="cc" id="country">
                <option value="">Select One...</option>
                <?php
                $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM country');
                if(is_object($sql) && $sql->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    while($row = $sql->fetch_array())
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['cn'].'</option>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="sp">State/Province</label></td>
        <td><select name="sp" id="state"><option>Select One...</option></select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="pcode">Postal Code</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pcode" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="active">Set Default</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="active" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Address" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#country").change(function(){
        var country_id = $(this).val();
        if(country_id != ""){
            $.ajax({
                url:"get-states.php",
                data: {c_id:country_id},
                type:"POST",
                success:function(response){
                    var resp = $.trim(response);
                    $("#state").html(resp);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#state").html("<option value=''>Select One...</option>");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php
require_once 'includes/functions.php';

if(isset($_POST['c_id']))
{
    $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM states WHERE ccid = "'.$_POST['c_id'].'"');
    if(is_object($sql) && $sql->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="">Select One...</option>';
        while($row = $sql->fetch_array())
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['sname'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option value="">ERROR</option>';
    }
}
else
{
    redirect('./');
}
?>
```

I converted all the states / provinces, and the countries to entries in my MySQL database, and with the queries above, it now works.  I also had to manually download the jquery.min.js file to my js folder to get it to actually work, as it did not want to read the remote file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably with your AJAX call.  You specify:

```
    contentType:"application/json; charset-utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
```

You are sending back HTML from your PHP page. Try that.  The /echo/html/ and other edits are for JSFiddle.  Just put back you old values for that, change the dataType and take out the contentType.

```
$("#cc").on("change",function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"process-request.php",
        data: { cc : selected },
        dataType:"html",
        async:false,
        success: ccSuccess,
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
});

function ccSuccess(result)
{       alert(result);
    $("#response").html(result);
}

function AjaxFailed(result)
{
    $("#response").html("<p class='error'>Failed to Load State/Province Codes</p>");
}
```

Comment: P.S.  Your need quotes around your method, "POST".

Comment: So, tried what you suggested (including putting quotes around the POST method), and still is not working at all.  I have tried it in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, all with the same result.

Comment: What do you get back from the PHP page, if anything ?  If you know how to use dev tools and the network tab you should be able to see a) status 200, 404, 500, etc. for the AJAX post, b)  Response from the PHP page, and if you use the alert of console.log(result) in you ccSuccess function the response from the server.

Comment: I edited my answer to take out the JSFiddle stuff and just put yours back in.  Tried it on my server locally and it works.  Check those other things and make sure you are not getting any PHP errors also.  You probably can use async also.  The response from the server will be a few ms probably.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to access all of that, as I do not have access to the logs of the server (My FTP for the server is locked to the www folder by the host).

I was however able to get it working by using new code I found with another google search, and it now works perfectly.  Updating original post with new information momentarily.

Comment: That is kind of weird.  It works on mys server PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

Do a `return json_encode($countryArr[$country])` in your php script. Remove the echo part.

```
function ccSuccess(result)
{       
 alert(result);

var country = JSON.parse(result);
var html = "";
   html += "<select name='sp'>";
    for(var i =0; i < country.length; i++)
    {
        html +="<option value='"+ country[i] +"'>"+ country[i] +"</option>";
    }
    html += "</select>";
    $("#response").html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataType:"json",`
You need to remove this line as you are not returning json from process-request.php it is simply returning html code.